# UITableView dynamic cell height with image view

Tags: ios, uitableview

Tableview contains UIImageView, image may or may not come. If not then how to compress the height of image view.
I have change the height constant to 0.
But gives me auto layout confliction warning, when scroll down and then up to that particular cell.
Another UIVIEW is below the image view. 
Content hugging priority of that is 250, 251
And resistant is 750, 749.

Comment: Do you want the height/width of your image view to be fixed ? or does it change dynamically ? Also could you please give more precisions about the other view in your cell, and what constraints you are setting?

Comment: If the image link is not coming from website then image view height should be compress

Comment: For the image view leading trailing up and height, below view up left right and bottom with hugging and resistant priority.

Comment: Okay thanks for the details. And what happens when you run the app? Do the image & view appear?

Comment: Yes they appear every time. At first 5 cell there is image the after that no image. If I scroll down then image view constant height I m setting is 0, then I scroll up , I have set the constant to 200. And it appears perfectly fine. But this time console is making constraint warnings .

Comment: Hmm I am not sure I understand, do you mean that you set a different height constant every time the user scroll down or up ?

Comment: When imagelink is nil then height constant 0 otherwise 200

Comment: Oh okay I see :). Well I would bet that the problem is coming from your second view (the one below). what kind of warning do you get from the console?

Comment: Normal auto layout warnings